# CSS Left Column fluid & Right Column fixed width

Tags: css

I've found a fiddle and seems to be working with  Left Column **FIXED** & Right Column **FLUID** width

http://jsfiddle.net/gpxeF/1742/

```
<div id=fixedWidth>
Fixed</div>
<div id=theRest>
    The rest of the space<br />The Rest?</div>

#fixedWidth{ 
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
#theRest{
    background: green;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

but when I tried to modify it by making the **Left Column to be fluid & Right Column to be fixed width**, then there goes the problem.

I trying to achieve a **Left Column to be fluid & Right Column to be fixed width** but its not working.

What i did was interchange their css then replaced "left" to "right".

here's my modified fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gpxeF/1744/

```
#fixedWidth{ 
    background: green;
    padding-right: 200px;

}

#theRest{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your second div is absolutely positioned, `right:0` needs to be added to make it stick to the right, instead of `float:right`. I edited your fiddle, take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/oLuzay16/

We can also use css `width:calc(100% - 200px);` to make the width of the first div 100% of the container minus 200px to account for the absolutely positioned div. `Calc` will work in most newer browsers, check here for a complete list: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc